# Order of execution with angular and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, data-binding

I need to render a few carousels (and other data) in the home page. I have a service to get all the data related to page (in single request). I am trying to use ng-repeat to render items in each carousel. There is also some jQuery script, which needs to execute after all bindings (to render carousels and other JQ components).

My controller looks like:

```
angular.module("app").controller('homeController',['httpService',
function (httpService) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.init = function () {
        httpService.get('home/GetHomeData', {}).then(function(res) {
            vm.data = res;
        })
    }
    vm.getFeaturedModels = function(){
        return vm.data.FeaturedProducts;
    }
}]);
```

And the page:

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-controller="homeController as vm" ng-init="vm.init()">
...
<ul class="list-inline owl-slider" >
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="m in vm.data.FeaturedModels">
                    {{m.Name}}
    </li>
</ul>
...
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        App.init();
    });
</script>
```

When I run the app, it gives weird results. First, it doesn't show the carousels and there is an error - `FeaturedProducts of undefined`. I guess this is because the ng-repeat is getting executed before the ajax is complete.

After some research, I changed the ng-repeat call to direct data object (`vm.data.FeaturedProducts` instead of `vm.getFeaturedProducts()`). Though doesn't sound great, it worked without errors. However the carousel is not rendered the way it is supposed to be. Some dynamically created divs are not proper. I suppose the script has got executed before the ng-repeat finish its task.

Alternatively, I tried to execute the script after the promise. Its of no use.

Is there a way control the order execution in this case? or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

the `ngReapeat` is executed on model change so it's not the case that it's executed before ajax, `$http` returns response object that contains the data so it should be `vm.data = res.data` or `vm.data.data.FeaturedModels` that's why you are getting the `FeaturedProducts of undefined`

```
angular.module("app").controller('homeController',['httpService', '$timeout',
function (httpService, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.init = function () {
        httpService.get('home/GetHomeData', {}).then(function(res) {
            vm.data = res.data;
        }).then(function(){
          $timeout(function(){
            //jQuery code to create carousels, $timeout ensures that the code will run in next $digest cycle so after DOM from ngRepeat get's created
          })
        })
    }
    vm.getFeaturedModels = function(){
        return vm.data.FeaturedProducts;
    }
}]);
```